# CherryPy, SQLAlchemy Core thread safety?

Tags: thread-safety, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

in my web based app, i decided to use Cherrypy 3.2 as http framework.

I am using the `cherrypy.Application` class to create WSGI compatible appliaction object, which is served via Apache2 with mod_wsgi.

Also, I am using just core components of SQLalchemy 0.7.3 (not ORM). There are available some tools for cherrypy for correct session binding per request (like [SATools](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/758ddd5a0a02/web/database/sql_alchemy)). But Session object of SQLalchemy is part of the ORM, not the core.

So I have started thinking about how to make similar tool but without session.

The documentation of SQLalchemy says:

> For a multiple-process application that uses the os.fork system call,
>   or for example the Python multiprocessing module, it’s usually
>   required that a separate Engine be used for each child process.

So how to correctly create one engine per cherrypy thread? Taking note that the threads are created by apache2 (probably).

Thank you!!

**edit**: it is maybe important, that wsgi application is ran in daemon mode by apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under mod_wsgi I don't think this is an issue if I understand the question because the application isn't preloaded into memory prior to the fork in mod_wsgi. Instead, the application is separately loaded into each distinct process so there are no issues from shared stuff due to inheritance across a fork.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I was testing it and I think that the application object is actually shared across the threads.

Comment: I have edited the question, added the information that wsgi app is used in daemon mode (maybe important in this case)

Comment: Processes are different to threads. I focused on the quoted text, which talks about os.fork. This implies it is talking about processes and not threads. I thus took it that you were getting confused in believing you ned one per thread, which I can't see that you would need based on the quoted section.

Comment: Sorry for late. I figured everything out now. I had mixed thread and processes together.